# How can I update date of datetime field with mysql only?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, sql-update

I have a table like this

```
| ID |         DATE              | DURATION |     STATUS | DUPLICATION |
|----|------------------- -------|----------|------------|-------------|
|  1 | January, 08 2014 19:30:12 | 00:00:03 |    Aborted |      (null) |
|  2 | January, 08 2014 19:30:12 | 00:00:06 |    Dropped |      (null) |
|  3 | January, 08 2014 05:25:11 | 00:00:20 |  Connected |    Multiple |
|  4 | January, 08 2014 05:19:21 | 00:00:21 |  Connected |      Repeat |
|  5 | January, 08 2014 05:12:56 | 00:00:20 |  Connected |      Unique |
|  6 | January, 08 2014 04:46:56 | 00:00:41 | Unanswered |    Multiple |
|  7 | January, 08 2014 04:42:56 | 00:00:35 | Unanswered |      Repeat |
|  8 | January, 08 2014 04:34:56 | 00:00:31 | Unanswered |      Unique |
|  9 | January, 09 2014 12:06:32 | 00:00:06 |    Dropped |      (null) |
| 10 | January, 09 2014 12:06:32 | 00:00:03 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 11 | January, 09 2014 05:25:11 | 00:00:20 |  Connected |    Multiple |
| 12 | January, 09 2014 05:19:21 | 00:00:21 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 13 | January, 09 2014 05:12:56 | 00:00:20 |  Connected |      Unique |
| 14 | January, 09 2014 04:46:56 | 00:00:41 | Unanswered |    Multiple |
| 15 | January, 09 2014 04:42:56 | 00:00:35 | Unanswered |      Repeat |
| 16 | January, 09 2014 04:34:56 | 00:00:31 | Unanswered |      Unique |
| 17 | January, 09 2014 12:19:01 | 00:00:20 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 18 | January, 09 2014 12:19:01 | 00:00:19 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 19 | January, 09 2014 12:15:30 | 00:00:20 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 20 | January, 09 2014 12:15:30 | 00:00:19 |  Connected |      Unique |
| 21 | January, 09 2014 07:25:11 | 00:00:41 |  Connected |    Multiple |
| 22 | January, 09 2014 07:19:21 | 00:00:27 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 23 | January, 09 2014 07:12:56 | 00:00:20 |  Connected |      Unique |
| 24 | January, 09 2014 06:46:56 | 00:00:32 | Unanswered |      Unique |
| 25 | January, 09 2014 06:42:56 | 00:00:29 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 26 | January, 09 2014 06:34:56 | 00:00:27 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 27 | January, 09 2014 05:34:56 | 00:00:27 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 28 | January, 09 2014 05:25:11 | 00:00:41 |  Connected |    Multiple |
| 29 | January, 09 2014 05:19:21 | 00:00:27 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 30 | January, 09 2014 05:12:56 | 00:00:20 |  Connected |      Unique |
```

I want to update only the date but dont know where to start from. I mean in the datetime field `date` i want to update the date '2014-01-08' to '2014-01-01'. How can i do that?
I have tried this.

```
UPDATE calldate cd
INNER JOIN calldate cdl ON cdl.id = cd.id
SET cd.date = ''/*Dont know what to do here */
WHERE DATE(cd.date) = '2014-01-08'
```

Here is the 

#### Fiddle Structure

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One option is to use this:

```
UPDATE `calldata`
SET `date` = DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE DATE(`date`) = '2014-01-08'
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d71/1

For better performance use the following query because index (if any) can be used by MySQL as `DATE()` is not on the left side of comparison operator:

```
UPDATE `calldata`
SET `date` = DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
WHERE `date` >= '2014-01-08'
AND `date` < '2014-01-09
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e7b2/1

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
UPDATE calldata
SET date = CONCAT('2014-01-01 ', TIME(date))
WHERE DATE(date) = '2014-01-08'
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/53279/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ID |                           DATE |                       DURATION |     STATUS | DUPLICATION |
|----|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|------------|-------------|
|  1 | January, 01 2014 19:30:12+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:03+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
|  2 | January, 01 2014 19:30:12+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:06+0000 |    Dropped |      (null) |
|  3 | January, 01 2014 05:25:11+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |  Connected |    Multiple |
|  4 | January, 01 2014 05:19:21+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:21+0000 |  Connected |      Repeat |
|  5 | January, 01 2014 05:12:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |  Connected |      Unique |
|  6 | January, 01 2014 04:46:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:41+0000 | Unanswered |    Multiple |
|  7 | January, 01 2014 04:42:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:35+0000 | Unanswered |      Repeat |
|  8 | January, 01 2014 04:34:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:31+0000 | Unanswered |      Unique |
|  9 | January, 09 2014 12:06:32+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:06+0000 |    Dropped |      (null) |
| 10 | January, 09 2014 12:06:32+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:03+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 11 | January, 09 2014 05:25:11+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |  Connected |    Multiple |
| 12 | January, 09 2014 05:19:21+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:21+0000 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 13 | January, 09 2014 05:12:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |  Connected |      Unique |
| 14 | January, 09 2014 04:46:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:41+0000 | Unanswered |    Multiple |
| 15 | January, 09 2014 04:42:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:35+0000 | Unanswered |      Repeat |
| 16 | January, 09 2014 04:34:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:31+0000 | Unanswered |      Unique |
| 17 | January, 09 2014 12:19:01+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 18 | January, 09 2014 12:19:01+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:19+0000 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 19 | January, 09 2014 12:15:30+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 20 | January, 09 2014 12:15:30+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:19+0000 |  Connected |      Unique |
| 21 | January, 09 2014 07:25:11+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:41+0000 |  Connected |    Multiple |
| 22 | January, 09 2014 07:19:21+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:27+0000 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 23 | January, 09 2014 07:12:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |  Connected |      Unique |
| 24 | January, 09 2014 06:46:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:32+0000 | Unanswered |      Unique |
| 25 | January, 09 2014 06:42:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:29+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 26 | January, 09 2014 06:34:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:27+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 27 | January, 09 2014 05:34:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:27+0000 |    Aborted |      (null) |
| 28 | January, 09 2014 05:25:11+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:41+0000 |  Connected |    Multiple |
| 29 | January, 09 2014 05:19:21+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:27+0000 |  Connected |      Repeat |
| 30 | January, 09 2014 05:12:56+0000 | January, 01 1970 00:00:20+0000 |  Connected |      Unique |
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE calldata
SET date = '2014-01-01'
WHERE DATE(date) = '2014-01-08'
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c84c/1)

Comment: I have tried this. This is not updating somehow and i am unable to understand why?

Comment: It does!! @raheelshan

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE calldata SET date = '2014-01-01' WHERE DATE(date) = '2014-01-01'
```

and

```
UPDATE calldata SET date = '2014-01-01' WHERE date = '2014-01-01'
```

two cases will work without any issue and in my case date is of type datetime.